# Find the argument of a complex number $z$

Tags: complex-numbers

$z$ is a complex number $z=2+\sqrt 3+ i$

I found that $\tan(a)=\frac{1}{(2+\sqrt 3 )}$
What am i supposed to do next?
Without using calculator, please

Comment: Can you find the value in this table? http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/simpleTrig.html

Comment: Hint:
$$
\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{3}} = 
\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{3}} \frac{  2-\sqrt{3} }{  2-\sqrt{3} } = \ldots
$$

Answer (score 1):

As Matti P. already hinted: $\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{3}} = 2 - \sqrt{3}$ which is $\tan(\frac{\pi}{12})$ or $\tan(15^\circ)$ if you prefer degrees over radians. As $|z|^2 = (2+\sqrt{3})^2 + 1^2 = 8 + 4\sqrt{3}$ we get that

$$z = 2\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3}}e^{i \frac{\pi}{12}}$$

in polar representation.